# Qss 10 year green card visa expired

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-expiration

I went to Italy for a year and a half. I had a good reason to stay so long but I can't stay here anymore. My husband is in the US. He's a citizen.

Can I go back with an expired visa? Should I chance it?  Do they really know if I've been away for over a year? Is it just a NTA and I can still get in? Or should I get an ESTA to get back in to see my husband? As a LPR can I even get an ESTA? I'm getting a ticket at the end of this month. I've been a resident since 1970s. Anyone actually work at the CBP that knows the protocol?

Comment: Nothing I’ve ever seen relating to US Immigration indicates that ‘chance it’ is a good idea. That’s if you even managed to board the flight.

Comment: Are you intending to return permanently? https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/returning-resident.html#1

Answer (score 5):

You should not apply for ESTA unless you intend to abandon your permanent residence.  If you do not want to abandon your permanent residence, you can [apply for a returning resident visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/returning-resident.html#1) (thanks to [Traveller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/60926/traveller) for the link).

If you do intend to abandon your permanent residence, I believe you can do that either with a consular officer at the consulate or embassy, or with an immigration officer at the border.